# Inserting images into TeXstudio

Tags: texstudio

I am using TeXstudio on my Lenovo laptop, and am running into an exasperating difficulty. Whenever I try to drag my file image into the "typing area," all that comes up is a bunch of gibberish. Here is excerpt of this gibberish:

```
ÿØÿà 2!!22222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222222ÿÀ
```

And there is much, much more of this. Previously, I could drag the file image into the "typing area" with ease, and actually preferred this method to the one in which I had to do all the typing--that is, the work--, because it would allow me to easily specify certain characteristics of the image (where I wanted to place the image on the image, how large I wanted the image, etc).

How can one go about remedying this?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling TeXStudio? What operating system? One of the developers, Tim Hoffmann, visits the site now and then, perhaps he'll see the question. If no one here can answer, you could try the [forum on Sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907839) or [the mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/texstudio-list).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Torbjorn T, I'm terribly sorry that I have not responded--I have been rather busy. I figured out the problem, though. I was trying to import PNG files, and for some reason TeXstudio wasn't too fond of this file format; after having converted to JPEG, I was able to import the file.

Answer (score 3):

You were probably using uppercase letters in the extension (e.g. foo.PNG). These were not recognized as images in TXS (will be fixed in the next version).

As a workaround you may change the extensions to lowercase. These extensions currently work: *.eps *.jpg *.png *.pdf